# Emailing onclick button to retrieve user email

Tags: javascript, email, drupal, drupal-7

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about adding a "Accept" button to an email that when the users clicks the button it adds their email to a database.

The main doubt is about taking the users email on the click action, so I can redirect the button to a landing page, and retrieve the parameters (email).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest solution is while setting up the "Accept" button/anchor in email template, add email address in the arguments of URL so when user clicks then you can easily get and save email in your database.

Comment: @usmanjutt84 I see, I had not thought about that option. Will take  a look. Apreciate your comment.

Comment: My default email sender was not able to add dynamic tags, so I had to move to another one, but this solution worked fine, do you want to write an answer so I can upvote you ? @usmanjutt84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, you only have to do two steps in Drupal..

- Setting up your Email template and add receiver email in URL argument(s) (like `https://www.example.com/get-user-email-page?user_email=example@example.com`) for anchor/button
- When user visit such URL, check the argument(s) in URL if available get and save in the database.

Hope this would work for someone.